# Good torrent client with file selection needed

Tags: bittorrent, selection

I normally use Transmission as a BT client on my Mac. Great app, but not for 1 type of torrent I download on regular basis.

The torrent is 30-40 Gb, with around 10000 files. I only need 200-300 files consuming maybe 50 Mb most of the time.

I need a BT client that is capable of selecting just the wanted files.

- It needs a sorting option for
  filenames (by default they are mixed
  up). Transmission fails on this as no
  sorting is possible
- It may only create the requested
  files in the download folder.
  Transmission fails on this aspect as
  it creates all files that share BT
  download chunks with the requested
  files too. VUZE fails even more on
  this as it creates all 10000 files as
  empty file first, thus waisting 40
  Gb.
- The client runs either on Win XP or
  on OSX 10.4

Anybody knows a BT client for this?

Comment: Why do you need to keep downloading a specific torrent?

Comment: ‘by default they are mixed up’: actually they're presented in the same order as they're stored in the torrent file, so it depends on the tool that created the torrent whether the order they appear in is of any use or not.

Comment: The company delivers a torrent every month. It's just a different version. But it is a returning process.

@bobince: uTorrent solves the sorting and selecting. It works great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Windows, uTorrent has this function.

It's still Beta for Mac, but worth a try: http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/mac

Comment: The OSX version has ridicule system requirements. 10.5 minimum, where BT clients ideally run on the old macs catching dust.

Comment: Yikes, didn't realize that. If Azureus/Vuze doesn't have this function either, then I'm stuck too. Sorry!

Comment: I'm gonna try uTorrent at home. Hope that one does a better job.

Comment: uTorrent runs great on mac. As far as requiring 10.5, it's rare to find any new software that works on older versions of the OS. Buying new OS upgrades is almost a requirement on Macs since backwards compatibility breaks more with each update. Irrelevant for this question though, Transmission requires 10.5 as well.

Comment: They seem to be working on 10.4 support. The 10.5 development is one of those bad aspects on OSX. Windows developers support XP for all apps, where OSX developpers try to keep up with all the Eye-Candy steve throws out over us all the time. Basic functionality of 99% of new mac-apps would work great on 10.3 and 10.4 too. It's just lazyness+fanboyism that hurts serious OSX development.

Comment: Windows uTorrent did it. It works flawless. Even the time to list the 10000 files and switch them on and off on a Atom PC is short!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, addressing one of your points about Transmission, you can have it only download specific files, and it will only have copies on disk of the ones you select (and any files that happen to share a block of data with one of the files you want).

What you have to do:

1. Go into Transmission's preferences
2. Go to the Transfers section
3. Check the box for "Display 'adding transfer' options window

What this does, is present you with file selection before Transmission begins downloading anything, and then only the files you have checked get downloaded. You can't sort, that's true, but with if you have access to a text listing of the torrent's contents, you can do a text search ahead of time to find where they are (if it's not a neatly-sorted torrent file).

Comment: Transmission is not nearly as good with this, as it creates all files that share chunks with the requested files too. So you have to reselect your selection again after downloading. uTurrent stores all these unwanted chunks in 1 big temp file.

Comment: Oh that's cool, I didn't know that. Azureus/Vuze and Transmission both worked the same way, so I didn't realize there was an alternative.